# How to execute a "SET ROLE XXXX..." with Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, insert, role

I'm developing a web app (java) and I'm using Hibernate 4.1.4 and oracle 11g. By security's rules, the dbuser (the db user that app uses) doesnt have insert privileges. Then every time my app is gonna do a insert, it must execute the query "SET ROLE XXXX ...." before the insertion-query be executed. This "set role.." will give to dbuser the privileges to insert into some tables int that transaction. How to do it with Hibernate? I don't wanna put it in a default conf because I should execute the above query only in insertions (not to selects...). I tried do it on my save method:

```
public Object saveOrUpdate(Object entity) {
        Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("set role XXXX identified by XXXX");
        query.executeUpdate();
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
        return entity;
    }
```

but it doesnt work. I get the error "view or table not exist". When I try execute only the query.executeUpdate() or the saveOrUpdate(entity) no error happened.

I guess it is all. If you need more details, please ask to me. Thanks!

Comment: Did you mention two questions here? 1. Design how to do this? and 2. you are not able to run the 'set role..'query?

Comment: The main question is How to do that. I just put here the way I took and the result (maybe, this is the best way just need a little fix)